# Pub/Sub Subscribers message routing

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scenario where multiple subscribers are present on a single subscription.
The way I understand it is that no 2 subscribers get the same message (at the same time).
That's exactly what I need, avoid "double processing".
And each service instance deals with the part of the load.

However, I would like to know how messages are distributed between them.
If possible, I'd like to set the routing technique. Somehow.

My end goal is to try and implement some sort of an actor model, using Pub/Sub.
Avoid concurrency by confining the processing to a single instance (given an id, or whatever).

I tried using filters, but that requires static routes and multiple subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to control which messages are routed to which subscriber for a subscription. Assuming they are processing messages equally fast, they should receive about the same amount of load. If you need to control the way messages are routed, you can use filtering for static routing as you point out. If it needs to be more dynamic, you may need to stand up some kind of load balancer or other process that is aware of the way in which messages need to be distributed so that it can forward the messages to the correct receiver.

If you are just trying to process messages for each ID in order, then Pub/Sub's [ordered delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) may be the sufficient for you. While the subscriber that handles a particular key can change over time, messages for the same key will only be delivered to a single subscriber at a time and in the order in which they were published.

Comment: Thank you @Kamal!
I will definitely try ordered delivery.